# jboss 5.1 server

Tags: java, jboss5.x

The architectures of jboss 4.2.2 and jboss 5.1 are slightly different. What would be the relevant architecture of "F:\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\conf\web.xml" in jboss 5.1??

Comment: what do you mean when you say what would be relevant architecture of a web.xml. Files don't have architecture. Are you asking about the structure and what DTD/XSD the file should conform to?

Comment: actually i am working on the web.xml which is available in "jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\conf\web.xml",  so where can i find the same in Jboss 5.1.... can you specify the path of the same web.xml in  Jboss 5.1..?

Comment: What do you want to change in that file?

Comment: What would you indeed like to change in that file. This web.xml file is hardly ever need changing. You might have a very good reason, but you are aware that your own web application should have its own web.xml, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployer file you are looking for resides in:

```
jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer
```